# iOS Storyboard/Objective C - set UIView size programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard

I have a UIView in a UITableViewCell, defined in the storyboard, acting as an overlay. What I want to do is have the UIView completely cover the cell, and then shrink over time.

Just to test out resizing it i've done:

```
- (void) styleForAction:(DNAction *) action {
    [[self cooldownView] setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,10,10)]
    ...
```

The function is firing, because the rest of the UITableViewCell is being styled, but the UIView stays as wide and as tall as it is in the storyboard no matter what. the darker blue in the picture below is the cooldownView. I've also tried setting the bounds instead, and setting the frame of the view's label.

[image]

EDIT: The view is linked up in the storyboard and class.

Comment: code required.This won't get you any valid answers

Comment: that is the code. I'm trying to set the size of a UIView (cooldownView). If that's not the way to do it then there's the problem, someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: this one line means to us that a view cooldownView's frame is set to (0,0,10,10).Nothing more.So more code required

Comment: I said that i set it to (0,0,10,10) but it doesn't change, this is the problem.

Comment: @EvanWard, where do you add the view to you cell? Show us this code this code please. Or may be, you've added it in xib or storyboard? Also please addd to the question information about where you are trying to set new frame?(method and object where you call it)

Comment: make sure the outlet cooldownView  is connected

Answer (score -1):

Does this code work for you:

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

  UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"coolDownCell"];

  UIView *coolDownView = [[UIView alloc ]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.f,0.f,320.f,44.f)];

  [cell.contentView addSubview:coolDownView];

  [UIView animateWithDuration:.3f
                        delay:1.f
                      options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                   animations:^{

                     coolDownView.frame = CGRectZero;

                   }
                   completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: This is a guess, not an answer with explanation.

Comment: It might, but the cooldownView is in the storyboard, not added programmatically.

Comment: @EvanWard, that is not a significant difference.  In the code above, remove the `coolDownView initWithFrame` and `addSubview` lines and substitute `[self coolDownView]` for `coolDownView` in the animation block.